# arguments transposed by R paste command within loop

Tags: r, string, for-loop

Because of a bug in the neuralnet command in R, I am building a formula manually instead of using the '.' notation for all variables.  Inside of a loop, the paste function is transposing the "~" and "y" as shown below.

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
  f <- as.formula(paste(c("y",i,"~", paste(c("x1","x2"), collapse = " + ")), collapse=""))
  message(f)
}
```

produces:

```
~y1x1 + x2
~y2x1 + x2
~y3x1 + x2
```

I tried reversing the order of the "~" and "y", but that gives an error "unexpected symbol".  So the question is, how do I get:

```
y1~x1 + x2
y2~x1 + x2
y3~x1 + x2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a problem with the message? when I do print(f) it works.

Comment: BTW, `paste` is vectorized so no need in a `for` loop, just `paste(paste0("y", 1:3), "~", paste(c("x1","x2"), collapse = " + "))` should be enough

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Sarah is correct -- it is a problem with message().  I had another bug in the actual code, which is not in this example, and now I was able to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a method of producing 5 formula-objects with an `sapply`-loop. Note: Your current `for`-loop will over-write the `f`-values because you did not index the assignment:

```
sapply( paste("y",1:5,"~", paste(c("x1","x2"), collapse = " + "), 
                            sep="") , as.formula)

$`y1~x1 + x2`
y1 ~ x1 + x2
<environment: 0x121e1b668>

$`y2~x1 + x2`
y2 ~ x1 + x2
<environment: 0x121e1b668>

$`y3~x1 + x2`
y3 ~ x1 + x2
<environment: 0x121e1b668>

$`y4~x1 + x2`
y4 ~ x1 + x2
<environment: 0x121e1b668>

$`y5~x1 + x2`
y5 ~ x1 + x2
<environment: 0x121e1b668>
```

There is really no way to have any other structure than a list-object, since formulas are language constructs and typically need to be inside list or list like structures and use "[[" to gain access to their values.